# how to Generating bulk Authentication codes in php?

Tags: php, authentication, bulkinsert, secret-key, key-generator

I am trying to generate 1500 authentication code using the following code:

```
<?php
include "../include/top.php";
$count=1500;
$end=0;
while ($end<$count)
{
//generate an authentication code
$string="ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789";
$string= substr(str_shuffle($string),5,8) ;

//check whether generated code already exist
$query = "select count(*) from auth where code = '$string' ";
$stmt = prepare ($query);
execute($stmt);
$bind = mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $count);
check_bind_result($bind);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_free_result($stmt);

//If generated code does not already exist, insert it to Database table
if ($count == 0)
    {
    echo $string."<br>";
    $query = "insert into auth (Code) values ('$string')";
    $stmt = prepare ($query);
    execute($stmt);
    $end++;
    }
}
?>
```

It generated only 1024 codes, printed in browser and inserted in database. and then generated an error :Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in......
Then I changed the value of max_execution_time to 350 in php.ini and restarted the WAMP  and ran the same script again, but it generate only less than 1000 codes and the browser shows loading till completing the 350 seconds and generated an error :Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 350 seconds exceeded in......

Actually I want to generate One Lakh of codes in this method. How to run this script successfully for the value

```
$count=100000
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of more efficient ways of doing this. However if you use

```
 set_time_limit(0);
 ini_set("memory_limit", "-1");
```

You should have no problems.

Comment: I have tried it with $count=1500, but it generate only 667 codes, and the script execution never end.